# wordpress get_post_meta using global $user_ID

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to change a wordpress script. I want to get all meta posts using `get_post_meta`. But how to do that with starting from `$user_ID`. I mean that I have user ID and nothing more, and I want to get his meta posts, similar output as of `get_post_meta()`.

For example this example is close to what i need, but it not finding any posts, 0 posts are found.

```
<?php query_posts('author=32'); ?>
<?php if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `global $current_user` and [`get_currentuserinfo()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_currentuserinfo) to function populate the user ID for the `query_posts()` arguments.

```
<?php
// get the current user and populate
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();

// use the current user ID as the author and query for posts
$args = array( 'author' => $current_user->ID );
query_posts($args);
?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ): while( have_posts() ): the_post(); ?>
    <?php the_title(); ?>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
// The Query
query_posts('author=<id>');
// The Loop
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
"<a href="the_permalink();">"the_title();"</a>";
endwhile;
// Reset Query
wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Answer (score -2):

In Query() function author parameter is available.
you may find it [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Parameters)